# Why is this jquery ajax GET call to a C# method not working?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, http-get

I have a C# .NET MVC 5 project.  I'm trying to submit a GET request from ajax to a controller method on the server.  The problem is that, even though this jquery is being called, the GET always returns a 404.  Here is the js:

```
 var theArguments = { "prefix": prefix, "level": level, "number": number };
 $.ajax({
            url: "GetMasteryObjective",
            type: "GET",
            data: theArguments,
            //data: JSON.stringify({ prefix: "prefix", level: "level", number: "number" }),
            //url: "/MasteryObjectiveAPI/GetMasteryObjective?prefix=" + prefix + "&level=" + level + "&number=" + number,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () {
                console.log("Successfully queried the database to validate the given mastery objective.");
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("There was an error with trying to validate the mastery objective with the database.");
            }
        });
```

As you can see I've tried several variants of how the variables are submitted (commented out).  This is the controller method that is never getting hit.

```
[HttpGet]
//[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static MasteryObjective GetMasteryObjective(String prefix, String level, String number)
{
     //code here
}
```

Other methods in the same controller have no problem being posted to.  So maybe there's something I don't understand about GET?  I understand that it should be valid to submit variables with a GET request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow.  I just discovered the answer to my own question while creating this post.  I needed to remove `static` from my controller method.

Comment: Your last sentence was not part of the answer, but was a comment so I'll add it here; this user has [self answered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions) their own question, this is a good thing!

Answer (score 0):

Happy that, you have got the solution.

However, thinking that this may help others .....

One of the reason for ajax call not hitting the Method in controller is:

*If the controller method is under [Authorize] but the user is trying to hit without logging in.*

Solution: If want to allow unauthorized access to that method; mark that method has *[AllowAnonymous]*, otherwise log-in and then try.